# Connect to an already open terminal over SSH

Tags: command-line, 18.04, ssh, gnome-terminal, remote

My specific example, I run a few Minecraft servers and was wondering if there's a way to interact with the terminals that host the servers over SSH.

Comment: Have you tried the ``screens`` command or ``tmux``? They allow you to save your terminal sessions so that you may sign on at a later time and continue interacting with those sessions. This keeps you from killing running processes that are tied to your terminal. Is that what you are attempting to do or are you just attempting to ssh to the server?

Comment: `screen` is _exactly_ what I needed! Thanks @Gordster

Comment: I cannot recall any "Ubuntu Minecraft Server" tutorial that *didn't* include `screen`

Comment: added information to the answer if you wouldn't mind marking it as "answered". Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating this answer from the comments in case anyone needs it.

You can use the `screen` command to save terminal sessions that can be accessed at a later time. This keeps you from having to kill processes that may be attached to a terminal session. So one example of how this is useful is if you were going to start a huge data transfer. You can start a screen session, start transferring the data, go home and ssh to your work computer/server and access the session without the transfer being interrupted

`sudo apt install screen`

you can then run

`screen -S <screen name>` to create new screen session

`screen -ls`  list screen sessions

`screen -r <screen name>` attach to specific screen.

tmux is slowly replacing the screen command so I would recommend looking into that as well.